# Can you fake flash?

Tags: macos, flash, safari

I am trying to access sites that are powered by flash, but they keep hitting me with popups that tell me to install flash before I can even do non-flash things. 
I refuse to use flash,

Is there a Safari or OS/X plugin/app that can make me appear to be using flash when I'm really not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the "Click to Flash" and "Click to Plugin" Safari extensions (and I believe you can still find the versions that work as plug-ins for any browser via the old Netscape plug-in API) pretend to be Flash, but don't actually load Flash until you click inside the grey Flash-replacement rectangle they draw in place of the Flash app.

See if those meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome has its own version of flash, and you don't need to install a flash plugin to the OS or other browsers